# Does writing $f(x)\sim \ell$ have a sense?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, asymptotics

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$, is it correct to say that $f(x)\sim_a \ell$ ? I would say yes since $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}=1$, but on a test I wrote $e^{-t}\sim_0 1$ and the corrector said that it's wrong to say that.
So, what's wrong ?

Comment: What is the definition of $\sim_a$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The one I know is $f\sim_a g\iff \lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=1$.

Comment: $f(x)\sim_a g(x)\iff f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x))$ when $x\to a$.

Comment: If $\ell = 0$, then $f(x) \sim_a \ell$ has an obvious problem.

Comment: I'd say it's right, but seldom expressed that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I'd say it's true. From the property of the limit we get $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$, so there are two bounds, say $L-\frac{1}{n}, L+\frac{1}{n}$ such that $f(x)$ is within these bounds. Hence the ratio is 1 by squeeze lemma.

Comment: could the downvoter please explain?